# Ошибка подключения файла css на Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Подключаю файл `css` через `functions.php` в Wordpress. 
В результате выдаёт ошибку:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

Файл подключен, так как в консоли могу видеть исходный код. Файл минифицирован.

`@charset "UTF-8";*{padding:0;margin:0;border:0}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box}:active`

В чём может быть ошибка? Необходимые скриншоты прикреплю.

Файл functions.php
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажи как ты подключил файл в function.php

Comment: @AndreyFreiz обновил описание вопроса. Там можете увидеть файл functions.php.

Comment: Код должен быть кодом, а не картинкой. И теги `html` и `css` тут совершенно лишние. Исправляй вопрос.

Comment: @SeVlad, я уже дал ответ, не думаю что есть нужна в исправлении

Comment: @AndreyFreiz это печально, что не думаешь. Надо и думать и читать правила SO

Answer (score 1):

Зачем ты вызываешь `wp_enqueue_script`
Попробуй сделать так

```
<?php
function register_styles() {
wp_register_style('all', get_template_directory_uri() .'/build/all.css');
wp_enqueue_style('all');'

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue', 'register_styles' );
```

Comment: работает, спасибо!

Comment: @ЕгорКоротцев если ответ помог - отметь его решенным *(и другие ответы на твои вопросы -тоже)*. А вопрос всё равно надо исправить.